# Reasoning behind time taken remaining same even when the actual path is longer than initial case

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Consider a particle which is at a distance d from origin , it approaches it with constant speed $v_°$ , so time taken will be $\frac{d}{v_°}$ , consider the same particle with constant speed $v_°$ along the line joining his instantaneous position with origin but now its also rotating about origin with radius being the distance between his instantenous position and origin at constant $\frac{v_°}{2}$ speed always .

> My question is why the time taken still remains same to reach origin ? As such the path traced would be longer than intial one and also  so why time remaining same ?

Comment: The length of path traced has changed, but the speed provided to the particle has changed as well. Why do you think that the time taken must necessarily change?

Comment: The fact that it reaches the origin in the same time is simply due to the fact that the speed with which the separation between the particle and the origin changes remains constant, and equal to $v_0$. The **tangential** velocity of the particle causing it to have a spiral trajectory does not contribute to the rate of change of the separation between the particle and the origin.

Comment: Thanks i got it now